# Zero-out data pointed by char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, buffer

I am trying to zero-out the data pointed by a char pointer like :

```c
int my_function(char *data) {

    // something here...

    memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));

    //...
}
```

It does not works because `memset` function is applied on pointer and not on data it-self.

How can I call `memset` function on data it-self into the memory ?

Comment: Re “It does not works because `memset` function is applied on pointer and not on data it-self”: Do you mean the `sizeof` operator is applied to `data`, which is the function parameter and is a pointer, rather than being applied to the original array holding the data? The C standard does not provide any way to know the size of an array from a pointer. You must design `my_function` to receive the length of the data in some either way, such as another parameter. If `data` points to a string (a null-terminated sequence of characters), you can get its length with `strlen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(data)` returns the size in bytes of the type of the object `data`, a `char*` in this case, i.e. it returns exactly how many bytes it takes to store a character **pointer** but not the actual character array. The `char*` type does not store the size of the character array to which it points, you must store that size separately in an `size_t` (see 1).

`void* memset( void* str, int ch, size_t n);`

`n` is the number of bytes starting from the location `str` that will all be set to the value `ch`. The size in bytes of an array of type `T` having `n` elements is returned (in a `size_t`) by `sizeof(T[n])`.

1: `size_t` behaves exactly as an `unsigned int` but may have different numerical capacity, it's maximum is the most number of bytes you can allocate to an array.

Comment: Sizes should be stored in a `size_t`, not an `int`, absent confounding factors.